# How to find the first odd digit in an integer recursively

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I am new to python and am trying to get more comfortable with recursion.  I am trying to find the first odd digit of a integer recursively.  If there are no odd digits found return -1.  Whenever I run this code I always get 35 instead of just 5.

This is what I have tried

```
def first_odd(n):
  if n == 0:
    return 0
  elif n % 2 == 1:
    return first_odd(n//10) * 10 + n%10
  else:
    return first_odd(n//10)
print(first_odd(2345))
```

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: Oh it was the title, how to find the first odd digit of an integer recursively

Comment: Yes, but you don't state that there's anything wrong with the code you posted in the question.  Unless told otherwise, I'm going to assume it works just fine.

Comment: Ahh It only returns all of the odd digits and not the first odd digit in the integer.  Sorry I am new to asking questions on Stack Overflow

Comment: Does it work???

Comment: What happens when no odd digit is found? Return None?

Comment: Ok I made the question a bit clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were basically on the correct track but just included an extra recursion you didn't need.  Consider:

```
def first_odd(n):
    if n == 0:
        return -1

    if n % 2 == 1:  # number is odd, return last digit
        return n % 10

    return first_odd(n // 10)
```

If this works as intended, then I might implement it as follows to combine a couple of the divisions:

```
def first_odd(n):
    if n == 0:
        return -1

    quotient, remainder = divmod(n, 10)

    if remainder % 2 == 1:  # remainder is odd, return it
        return remainder

    return first_odd(quotient)
```

> Is there also a way to find the first odd digit from left to right
> using 1 parameter?

```
from math import log10

def first_left_odd(n):
    if n == 0:
        return -1

    power = 10 ** int(log10(n))

    digit = n // power

    if digit % 2 == 1:
        return digit

    return first_left_odd(n - digit * power)
```

Or if using the math library and/or `log10()` is an issue, then:

```
def first_left_odd(n):
    if n < 10:
        return n if n % 2 == 1 else -1

    result = first_left_odd(n // 10)

    if result != -1:
        return result

    return first_left_odd(n % 10)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  :)  Is there also a way to find the first odd digit from left to right using 1 parameter?  Tarik already answered it but I would like to use 1 parameter if possible.

Comment: @Squishy, I've added a one parameter left-to-right solution using `log10` from the math library.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your recent comment to Tarik correctly, it sounds like you want a function that will return the first odd digit **scanning an integer right to left** and if no odd digits are found then return -1.  For example, in your original post you stated that with the integer `2345` you expected the value of `3`, but based on your comment it sounds like `5` would be the correct answer scanning right to left, right?  If so, then the following code should meet that description.

```
from random import randint

def find_rightmost_odd_digit(number):
    while number:
        rightmost_digit = number % 10
        if rightmost_digit % 2:
            return rightmost_digit
        number = number // 10
    return -1

for _ in range(10):
    number = randint(0, 1000)
    print(f"{number:>10}{find_rightmost_odd_digit(number):>4}")
```

Output:

```
       387   7
        88  -1
       639   9
       196   9
       986   9
       232   3
        82  -1
       907   7
       948   9
       214   1
```

Comment: LOL, we have been solving this homework free of charge :-) +1 for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Building complex programs is a matter of combining several simple programs. For this problem I would write a program that breaks a number into `digits`, and one that checks if any particular number `is_odd` -

```py
def first_odd(n):
  for d in digits(n):
    if is_odd(d):
      return d
  return None
```

We can write `digits` and `is_odd` easily -

```py
def is_odd(n):
  return n & 1

def digits(n):
  if n < 0:
    yield from digits(n * -1)
  elif n < 10:
    yield n
  else:
    yield from digits(n // 10)
    yield n % 10
```

```py
print(first_odd(2345))     # 3
print(first_odd(6804721))  # 7
print(first_odd(2468))     # 9
print(first_odd(-465321))  # 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do it:

```
def first_odd(n, digit):
    if n == 0:
        return None
    elif n % 2 == 1:
        return digit
    else:
        return first_odd(n//10, digit+1)


first_odd(2345, 0)
```

If you want the first digit to be 1, pass 1 instead of 0

Ok, this is for left to right:

```
  def first_odd(n, digit):
    if n == 0:
        return None

    pos = first_odd(n//10, digit+1)
    if pos is None and n % 2 == 1:
        return digit
    else:
        return pos
```

Comment: LOL, ok will test.

Comment: Really? test it with 1230236.

Comment: Yeah it works for that but Im also trying to make it work for all numbers.  I meant for the first odd digit found in the integer from right to left.  Sorry if I worded the question a bit confusing

Comment: Is there also a way to go from left to right?  Just asking

Comment: I added it to my answer but did not test it yet. Try it and let me know if it does not work

Comment: You have already voted someone else as answering your question, although he is doing it right most. What do you want exactly?